# NTC Thermistor Trigger LED

Tags: led, temperature, thermistor

I'm wondering if anyone would be willing to help me with the basics here. I'd like to create a circuit, as small and simple as possible, with off-the-shelf components, that will allow me to turn on an LED when the temperature of this particular thermistor ([MA100BF103A](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MA100BF103A/235-1064-ND/272974)) exceeds 37 degrees C.

The resistance vs. temperature values for this thermistor are online [here](https://www.amphenol-sensors.com/index.php?option=com_edocman&task=document.download&id=329).

[image]

Is this even possible without something like an arduino? What parts would I need, besides the thermistor and an LED? How would I wire them together?

I'm a complete novice. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [Solved on this site already](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260703/question-about-thermostat-circuit), I think.

Comment: for this particular thermistor? link please?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what part of the referenced circuit you didn't understand or you think doesn't suit your application.

Comment: Opamp and some precision resistors.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I'm curious why you choose an op amp (lm358) over a comparator (say and lm393) for this? I'm trying to learn...

Comment: Most (well, many) comparators have open collector outputs. If you reverse the inputs and return the LED to V+, you'll be fine, but in the spirit of keeping it simple, it's more than I wanted to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get much simpler than this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ7lwj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As the temperature rises, the voltage on IN+ risis; at 37C it crosses the threshold and the LED switches on.

You posted the data for 5 thermistors, I'm assuming the correct one is the right and column based on the numbering (103) where 37C corresponds to 6.2k.

So I made all the other resistors in the bridge the same value, so that they are likely to be from the same batch, reducing error : 1% tolerance is probably good enough, go for 0.5% if you can afford it. Supply is not critical, a 9V battery is OK but 5V should work too. Or 2 Lithium coin cells, a bit smaller.

It appears that assumption is wrong; for the thermistor labelled "10K" the correct resistance is 6.016K. Simplest fix is to bring R4 down to (about) 6.016K by adding 200K in parallel with it, so that's what I have done. (6K resistors are a bit less readily available).

Adjust R5 for suitable brightness.

[The LM358 is a pretty standard opamp (datasheet here)](https://www.ti.com/product/LM358) - you probably want the LM358P or another variant with the DIP-8 package. On Digikey, eliminate "surface mount" from the search and it's easy to find.

And keep washing your hands.

Comment: 103 is a 10k NTC

Comment: Yeah but which one? I was assuming it was the "103(Y)" not the "10K" on the given data. They are slightly different at 37C, 6.2k vs 6k; the latter will switch at 36C.

Comment: This is awesome thank you! I think the one I have is the 10k - how would that change things?

Comment: @G36thanks for keeping me straight : bodged to update.

Comment: "keep washing your hands" - LOL yes!

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance - I've just started out with simple circuits using breadboards and have an assortment of parts, just a sampling of resistors, diodes, ICs, etc.  

The LM358 is some kind of amplifier, I take it, but could you recommend one specific one via a link to one on digikey perhaps?

Comment: Searching digikey for that name should yield several : you want one (get 2 or 3) rather than a reel of 4000, and you want DIP8 which is easier to handle than SO-8 or other SMD parts.

Comment: There are hundreds... (!) lots of variables and characteristics I'm not familiar with and not sure which to choose. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/687?k=lm358&k=&pkeyword=lm358&sv=0&sf=0&FV=-8%7C687&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Comment: @MattR One thing that we **do not** do here is provide recommendations for specific products or where to buy them. You should take the time to learn about op amps and you can sort through the options yourself.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - good to know, thanks.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks for your help. I'm attempting to go from your schematic to a breadboard layout using Fritzing and I'm not sure how to wire up the LM358 - do you have any advise?

Comment: Datasheet will give you the pinout. Connect the unused inputs (the other opamp) to -V. Add a decoupling capacitor across the supply. That's about it.